Cyclic Radioactivity
Radioactive isotopes can decay into non-radioactive or other radioactive elements.
We can make a reaction scheme that goes something like:
$$A \xrightarrow{\lambda_1} B \xrightarrow{\lambda_2} C$$
Where $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are the decay constants for the respective reaction.
This is a series radioactive scheme. Easily solvable and we have many examples for this sort of reaction to occur.
Cyclic Radioactivity
Consider such a reaction scheme:

We can solve this, and I have also solved this case, as can be seen in this desmos graph.
My question: Is such a reaction scheme possible with actual elements?

In a vacuum, this would violate energy conservation. Externally driven, I guess the CNO cycle occurring as part of stellar nuclear fusion is similar to what you are thinking of.

@paulina CNO cycles are mostly fusion reactions, where lighter elements fuse into heavier ones, and the last one in chain decays into primary element again. While OP talks about reverse - about radioactive decay, which is fission, which is only possible to decay into lighter elements. So unless somebody has catalysator which fuses $C$ back into $A$,- this is not possible.

For a little while you can get some cycling of elements (but not specific isotopes). One path in the 238U decay chain takes you along Po-Pb-Bi-Po-Pb-Bi-Po-Pb (see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Decay_chain%284n%2B2,_Uranium_series%29.svg). Again, the isotopes are different each time through, and the last isotope, 206Pb, is stable.

@AgniusVasiliauskas true, it was just the only example of any cyclic nuclear process i could think of.

@paulina Along similar lines, the final stages of the s-process in massive stars involves a cycle between seven isotopes.  But four of the steps involved are neutron captures rather than radioactive decays.

Some chemical reactions can oscillate for a short time. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_oscillator

Radioactivity is a spontaneous process, it's exothermic. The process you are proposing requires the $C$ nuclei to undergo an excitation instead of a de-excitation. So it won't happen naturally, or at least not without some very specific circumstances.
A driven possibility could be something like this: $A$ is a neutron rich nucleus that undergoes $\beta$ decay into an excited state $B$ that then undergoes $\gamma$ decay into $C$. Under an $(n,p)$ reaction you could effectively exchange one of the protons of $C$ into a neutron, going back to the $A$ state. But this kind of process won't follow an exponential law with decay constant $\lambda_C$, unless you specifically design it so.

Notably (and necessarily), none of the reactions is a fission. (No criticism, just a statement that was not made by the question author.)

And another observation is that the (n,p) reaction is where the nucleus gets the energy (in form of the n/p mass difference) which  it expends in the other two, right?

On the natural grounds, no it's not possible since in the nuclear fission heavier nuclei breaks into lighter ones until all reaction chains reaches some stable light elements. So decay reaction(s) of input element is more like "a decay tree" :

If you want to make the loop going back from lightest element $C$ to most heavier $A$,- you need :

Some nuclear fusion reaction chain which goes back from C to A (possibly in intermediate elements)
External and constant energy input for a fusion reaction, so as long as you keep this energy supply,- this catalyzed cycle can go on.


Would it be possible for the energy released in the reactions (A->B and B->C) be used up in a fusion reaction (C->A)? So, the energy would be present within the cycle..
And if it were possible, what would the rate equation look like? Would it be first order(like decay) or something else?

Typical fusion reactions (for example ones going in a Sun) are very energy-hungry, requires very high initial temperatures of sample for achieving minimum quantum tunnelling rates between nuclei to even start and keep it. So answer is - probably no, i.e. that energy released in a nuclear fission chains to keep fussion $C \to A$ going on is not enough.

Hypothetically at least you could harness some of the energy from the first two decays into fusing $C$, yes. But there would be inefficiencies. You would lose part of the energy you want to recollect from $A$ and $B$, and waste some of the energy you're using into fusing $C$ too. Meaning you'd still have to complement the system with an external source of energy. As for the rate equation, that would depend on exactly how the fusion process happens.

In any radioactive decay, the mass (= energy) of the atom must be conserved. However, since part of the rest mass of the atom is always turned into either kinetic energy or gamma radiation, every single decay must reduce the rest mass of the nucleus. With that in mind, it's obvious that such a decay cycle cannot exist.

There is one confounding quirk in the decay chains, however: For instance, you might be wondering, why there are $\beta+$ emiters (which convert a proton into a neutron) while the neutron itself is unstable and $\beta-$ decays into a proton... The answer is, that the free neutron is heavier than the proton, yet the additional energy required to cram too many protons into a nucleus causes all $\beta+$ emitters to be heavier than their decay products. As such, the resulting nucleus cannot turn back into the $\beta+$ emitter because that would violate energy conservation. The possibility of both $\beta-$ and $\beta+$ emitters looks weird at first, but in the end it's all just a matter of mass/energy differences between different nuclei and decay particles.

It's perfectly possible to have a two-state system in quantum mechanics that oscillates back and forth between the two states. It can be extended to three states, or any finite number of states, but two is the simplest case to discuss.
In fact, for a two-state system, oscillation back and forth is the only possible (nontrivial) behavior. A good example, discussed in the Feynman lectures, is the ammonia molecule, which can tunnel back and forth between two states, like an umbrella flipping inside out in a strong wind.
This is the only possible behavior. The mathematical proof of this may or may not be at an appropriate level for the OP's current knowledge, and is any case more of a side issue, but the basic idea is that the Hamiltonian is a Hermitian matrix, and therefore can be diagonalized by a unitary transformation, giving a result with real entries. This is just a theorem from linear algebra. So in the appropriate basis, there is no time evolution at all. For the ammonia molecule, what happens is that the states of good energy are superpositions of the two states that we intuitively think of as the two possible configurations.
So the mystery is actually the opposite of the one posed in your question. How can we get one-way radioactive decay, with irreversible evolution from state A to state B? The answer is that in radioactive decay, the initial state can be a single state, but the final state has to be an infinite number of states. The idea is that if, for example, a uranium nucleus emits an alpha particle, then the full description of the final state includes the momentum vector of the alpha particle, which can be emitted in any of an infinite number of directions. Since the space of states is infinite-dimensional, the theorem about Hermitian matrices doesn't apply -- a matrix is finite-dimensional.
Physically, what's happening is that the alpha particle has an infinite phase space to disappear into, and it's never coming back.
Really this doesn't have anything to do with conservation of energy. There is no reason why A and B can't have the same energy. That's the case for the ammonia molecule.

In radioactive decay, there is a reason why $A$ and $B$ cannot have the same energy, and that reason is that to get from $A$ to $B$, a particle is emitted, taking energy out of the system so that $B$ has less energy than $A$. Unless energy is put back into the system (which requires work to be done), conservation of energy is indeed the reason why there are no cyclic nuclear decay processes. Obviously, the math works out and shows connections to other physical properties of the system, but the core physical concept behind it all is energy conservation (which is an empirical assumption)
